# Html page Department F not in correct order

Tags: javascript, html, css

When i try to add Department F in html page,its not added in correct place please help me.

I updated the html code in fiddle link.

```
<div class="content">
<h1> Organization... </h1>
 <figure class="org-chart cf">
<ul class="administration">
  <li>                  
    <ul class="director">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><span>Director</span></a>
        <ul class="subdirector">
          <li><a href="#"><span>Assistante Director</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="departments cf">                             
          <li><a href="#"><span>Administration</span></a></li>

          <li class="department dep-a">
            <a href="#"><span>Department A</span></a>
            <ul class="sections">
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A1</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A2</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A3</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A4</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section A5</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="department dep-b">
            <a href="#"><span>Department B</span></a>
            <ul class="sections">
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B1</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B2</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B3</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section B4</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="department dep-c">
            <a href="#"><span>Department C</span></a>
            <ul class="sections">
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C1</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C2</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C3</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section C4</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="department dep-d">
            <a href="#"><span>Department D</span></a>
            <ul class="sections">
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D1</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D2</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D3</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D4</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D5</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section D6</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="department dep-e">
            <a href="#"><span>Department E</span></a>
            <ul class="sections">
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E1</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E2</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="department dep-e">
            <a href="#"><span>Department F</span></a>
            <ul class="sections">
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E1</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E2</span></a></li>
              <li class="section"><a href="#"><span>Section E3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </li>
</ul>           
</figure>
</div>
```

in the above html page i am newly added Department F,but the Department F is not beside of Department E,please help me!

I am also updated the code in Fiddle Link.https://jsfiddle.net/kxk8urhm/53/

Comment: by default hide all sections in departments,when click on specific department show that selections,how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce `.department`'s width and `.departments:after`'s left attributes like this:

```
.department{
...
width: 14.598949%;
...
}

.departments:after{
...
left: 7.1%;
width: 82.1%;
...
}
```

Editted fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/kxk8urhm/54/

Comment: When i try to add department G,not in correct position

Comment: You need to edit manually in every condition with this way.
.department{... width:12.598949%...}, .departments:after{... left:6.1%; width:86.1%; ...}. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kxk8urhm/56/  Or you can adjust them dynamicaly with jquery.

Comment: ok.can you please help how can i add departments dynamically through angularjs

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not much knowledgeable enough in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there should be a class dep-f in your html. You copied and paste for new tree view element for dep-F from E. So check for classes also.